# How to hide a div containing text behind an image in 3D transform

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've been trying to make three images with a 'flipcard' effect for around a day and a half now and think I'm pretty close to a solution.

However, as you can see on the codepen, the only problem left is that when my images are in a static state (i.e. not being hovered over) you can still see the text lying on top of them.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could come up with a way so that when the images are static, there is no text lying on top of them, but when they are hovered over they animate with the 'flipcard' effect - such as already occurs.

Basically, I'd just like the text hidden/removed when the images are in a static state but visible after the animation occurs - as if they were on the 'flipside' of the images! The rest is fine.

Appreciate any answers in advance, thanks guys! :-)

Codepen link - http://codepen.io/skoster7/pen/kkYEJk?editors=0100

HTML:

```
<div class="flexcontainer">
    <div class="photo-container">
        <div class="photo">
            <img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/kiXLfqncf42kg/200_s.gif" class="front" />
            <div class="photo-desc back">Christmas tree</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="photo-container">
        <div class="photo">
            <img src="http://hdwallpaperpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Happy-birthday-candles-on-cake-small-cake-hd-4k-wallpaper-300x200.jpg" class="front" />
            <div class="photo-desc back">Happy Birthday</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="photo-container">
        <div class="photo">
            <img src="https://www.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a76/thumb/halloween-jack-o039-lantern-pumpkin-ghost-cat-skull-spider.jpg" class="front" />
            <div class="photo-desc back">Halloween</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flexcontainer {
    display: flex;
    perspective: 700px;
}

.photo {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.photo-desc {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.photo-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-style: preserve-3d;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

    .photo-container:hover {
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }

.back {
    backface-visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10;
    margin-top: -200px;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `photo` and `back` elements should be siblings (and not parent/child).

Here is a snippet (changed width/height of the elements to fit SO):

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex; 
  perspective: 700px; 
}

.photo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px; 
  transform: rotateY(0deg); 
}
.photo img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.photo-container {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 2s; 
  position:relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px; 
  margin:10px;
}

.photo-container:hover {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg); 
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg); 
  color: red;
}
.photo,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden; 
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg); 
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">

  <div class="photo-container">
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/kiXLfqncf42kg/200_s.gif" class="front">
    </div>
    <div class="back">Christmas tree</div>
  </div>

  <div class="photo-container">
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="http://hdwallpaperpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Happy-birthday-candles-on-cake-small-cake-hd-4k-wallpaper-300x200.jpg" class="front">
    </div>
    <div class="back">Happy Birthday</div>
  </div>

  <div class="photo-container">
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="https://www.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a76/thumb/halloween-jack-o039-lantern-pumpkin-ghost-cat-skull-spider.jpg" class="front">
    </div>
    <div class="back">Halloween</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a working codepeng:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Egazvq?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding `display: none;` to the `.back` class

and then adding a little something to your css:

```
.photo-container:hover .back {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is an updated codepen as an example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKwRvA?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

Well, I enjoyed the challenge of this. I will go right ahead and add another solution for you.

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex; 
  perspective: 700px; 
}

.photo-desc { 
  position: absolute; 
}

.photo-container {  
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 100;  
  margin-right: 10px; 
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 2s; 
  transition-style: preserve-3d; 
}

.photo-container:hover {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10; 
  margin-top: -200px; 
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  color: red; 
  opacity: 0;
}
.photo-container:hover > .back {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">

  <div class="photo-container">
    <img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/kiXLfqncf42kg/200_s.gif" class="front">
    <div class="back">
      Christmas tree
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="photo-container">
     <img src="http://hdwallpaperpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Happy-birthday-candles-on-cake-small-cake-hd-4k-wallpaper-300x200.jpg" class="front">
    <div class="back">
      Happy Birthday
       </div>
       </div>
  
  <div class="photo-container">
    <img src="https://www.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a76/thumb/halloween-jack-o039-lantern-pumpkin-ghost-cat-skull-spider.jpg" class="front">
    <div class="photo-desc back">Halloween
    </div>
  </div>
  
  

</div>
```

Doing it this way, enables the text to "fade in" etc. Which i think looks kinda cool with your animation. I also got it so your images stay "appeared" when hovering over, rather than the flipside "disappearing" when animation is flipped.

As a side note:  disappointed that others found another solution first :)